# Tabulator Sorting Numbers

Tags: tabulator

I am sorting by a column with numbers in. I understand why the sorting puts 8.10 before 8.2, however is there a way to overcome this? I don't really want to have to ut 8.01 etc

I did try all the sort types but none gave the desired results

[image]

Comment: the number sorter should work just fine, without seeing how your table is setup it is hard to offer meaningful advice, please create a JS fiddle that shows your table setup and your sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like you are sorting the column as a string rather than a number, though i wouldnt be able to say for sure without a JS Fiddle to demonstrate the issue.

The solution is to set the `sorter` to `number` in the columns definition object. In the example below i am going to assume the column is called `score`:

```js
{title:"Score", field:"score", sorter:"number"}
```

That should the correctly sort by number